# Script to su -c into a screen is not working as intended

Tags: shell, shell-script, sudo, gnu-screen, su

I'm working on a script that will allow me to load up a screen from a user via sudo and su -c. However, when I use it, it will just show the shell of the user:

```
sudo su -c "script /dev/null; screen -r $2" $1
```

As it stands, it executes /dev/null (used to make accessing the screen in su possible).. but doesn't connect to the screen. I'm sure that the screen name is accurate and so is the user I am logging in as.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently run into this 'nesting doll' confusion with ssh+su+screen+rtorrent so I think I can help.

To achieve the desired results you can use;

`sudo su -c "script /dev/null -c \"screen -r $2\"" $1`

The way you are doing it now only launches `screen` **after `script` has terminated (via `exit`, etc) and has absolutely no effect on your `screen` session**. In the method above, you launch the `screen` command within the `script` session (`script -c`). Note the escaped (**\"**) quotes.

With that said, you are still doing it wrong. There is no point in using `sudo` and `su` together in this context (I can't think of any correct context). The solution is to use one or the other based on your implementation.

1. **sudo method** (requires a correctly configured sudoers file, can be used to bypass login):
   `sudo -u "$1" "script /dev/null -c \"screen -r $2\""`
2. su method (requires login generally, useful for root):
   `su "$1" -c "script /dev/null -c \"screen -r $2\""`

All of this information is available via the `man` pages (type q to exit). As a newbie, I find them extremely helpful:

`man su; man sudo; man script; man screen`

Or simply ask the program for help:

`su --help; sudo -h; script --help; screen --help`

Also, if anyone is coming here for rtorrent advice, the answer is:

`su ${user} -c "script /dev/null -qc \"screen -dr ${session_name}\""`

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is:

1. Run `script /dev/null`. This runs an interactive shell and puts the transcript of that session into `/dev/null`.
2. When the interactive shell exits, `script` terminates and `screen` starts.

I don't know why you're trying to use `script` here, especially when you don't want the transcript.

Using `su` in `sudo` is redundant: `sudo` has this functionality already.

```
sudo -u "$1" screen -r "$2"
```